# How to route with no hashtag in hashtag router in react?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

Anytime I call my router with something like `http://localhost:8080/login`, react-router edits the path, and reroutes it to `http://localhost:8080/login#/` (an invalid route), when I want it to reroute to `http://localhost:8080/#/login` (a valid route). How can I do this?

I've already tried adding

```
historyApiFallback: {
   index: '/'
},
```

to my webpack.config. I'm not sure how else to find this information.

My code:
https://pastebin.com/raw/XCvgV6rP

Comment: Could you share your routes config and calls? Out-of-the-box react-router is working exactly "valid".

Comment: Here's my code @AndyTheos https://pastebin.com/raw/XCvgV6rP

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you just need to use the BrowserRouter instead of the HashRouter that you currently import in your index.js file.

HashRouter uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e. window.location.hash) to keep your UI in sync with the URL, whereas BrowserRouter uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

Sources:
[HashRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md)
[BrowserRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/BrowserRouter.md)

Comment: The problem mentioned in the question is not about Router usage\selection. It is about incorrect redirecting\URLs.

Comment: @Andy Theos I know, but in general imo BrowserRouter is the better choice anyway for any recent React projects. Thats why I chose to only put that in my answer

Comment: Agreed, but from the question we can't get much info about project and reasons to use HashRouter.

Comment: So...implemented BrowserRouter, it didn't work well at all. It couldn't find the routes for some reason. Any idea how to get react to route from localhost/here to localhost/#/here?

Answer (score 0):

When you enter `http://localhost:8080/login` in browser's URL bar, after pressed Enter, browser moves you to `login`, then hash router adding his slash, making it `/login#/` in the end. If you are using `Link` and `history.push` then HashRouter will redirect just fine. With HashRouter you don't have `/login` per se.

Take a look @Marco answer though, probably you will be using BrowserRouter
 to get rid of those pesky hashbangs anyway.

Comment: using browserHistory and this leading # annoyingly keep coming! It doesn't make sense! It should not!